# Dropbox images to s3 bucket using java

Tags: amazon-s3, dropbox, dropbox-sdk

We are having a hugh set of images inside dropbox and manually downloading and uploading to S3 is not a practical method.Can anyone suggest the best method to transfer dropbox files with folder to s3 bucket.Java is the technology that we are planning to use.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's no fix for this, since you don't have access to dropbox servers. If you did own the servers that the files were stored on, then you'd have this similar issue: [How to upload files directly to Amazon S3 from a remote server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491025/how-to-upload-files-directly-to-amazon-s3-from-a-remote-server)

Answer (score 0):

You can either write a program to copy the files from Dropbox to AWS s3.
Or
You can use a third-party tool.

**DropBox**
Here is the official GitHub project [dropbox-sdk-java](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java) with code examples.

**AWS**
Here is the AWS Java SDK example code for [upload-object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html#upload-object)

**Full APIs references**

- Here are the APIs for [Dropbox getting-started-api](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/getting-started?_tk=guides_lp&_ad=guides2&_camp=get_started)
- Here are the APIs for [AWS S3 API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/Type_API_Reference.html)
- Here are the javadoc for [AWS JAVA SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html)

**Tools**
There are third-party tools for doing this.
Here are two examples:

- [inclowdz](https://inclowdz.wondershare.com/cloud-transfer/dropbox-to-s3-sync.html)
- [multcloud](https://www.multcloud.com/tutorials/backup-dropbox-to-amazon-s3.html)